# What is the multiplicative structure of K-theory $\Omega$-spectrum $KU$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

The K-theory $\Omega$-prespectrum $KU$ has spaces $KU_{2i}=BU\times \mathbb{Z}$ and $KU_{2i+1}=U$, according to Bott periodicity we have a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded cohomology theory $\tilde{K}^*(X)$, with $\tilde{K}^{2i}(X)=\tilde{K}(X)=[X,BU\times \mathbb{Z}]$ and $\tilde{K}^{2i+1}=\tilde{K}^1(X)=[X,U]$. Just as for any ring spectrum, there is a multiplicative map $\phi: KU_i \wedge KU_j \rightarrow KU_{i+j}$ which induce the $\cup$ product on $K^*(X)$, say $x\in \tilde{K}^i(X)=[X,KU_i]$ and $y\in \tilde{K}^j(X)=[X,KU_j]$, then $x \cup y$ lies in  $\tilde{K}^{i+j}(X)=[X,KU_{i+j}]$ by the following composition:
$$ X \xrightarrow {\bigtriangleup} X\times X \xrightarrow {x \times y} KU_i \wedge KU_j \xrightarrow {\phi} KU_{i+j} $$
So I was wondering what exactly is the map $\phi: KU_i \wedge KU_j \rightarrow KU_{i+j}$. To be more specific, how to describe the fllowing three maps $\phi: (BU\times \mathbb{Z})\wedge U \rightarrow U$, $\phi: (BU\times \mathbb{Z}) \wedge (BU\times \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow (BU\times \mathbb{Z})$ and $\phi: U\wedge U \rightarrow (BU\times \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: While I guess that you will find an answer in Switzer's book in this model, it may be good to take another perspective: the 0-th space $BU \times \mathbb{Z}$ is a grouplike $E_{\infty}$-ring space via $\oplus$ and $\otimes$. Every grouplike $E_{\infty}$-ring space is the infinite loop space of an up to equivalence unique connective $E_{\infty}$-ring spectrum (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.4550 and its references), which in this case is $ku$, the connective cover of $KU$. Inverting the Bott element in $\pi_2$ yields $KU$ and localizations preserve $E_{\infty}$-ring structures.

Comment: To paraphrase Lennart, often the multiplication in a generalised cohomology theory is best thought of in terms of the geometry (in this case $\otimes$ of vector bundles) rather than maps of classifying objects. Would you ask for a concrete map $K(R,i)\times K(R,j)\to K(R,i+j)$ representing cup product of singular cohomology classes?

Comment: Just to expand Mark's proposal to use geometry: the grading in K-theory can be implemented by an action of a Clifford algebra on vector bundles (degree $n$ corresponds to an action of $\mathbb{C}l_n$). Then, the tensor product of two such vector bundles will have an action of $\mathbb{C}l_{n_1} \otimes \mathbb{C}l_{n_2} = \mathbb{C}l_{n_1+n_2}$.

Comment: I suggest to look at Brayton Gray's book. Prior to the language of $E_\infty$-ring spaces and similar gadget, there is space level construction of the operations on $BO$ which provide sort of structures on $KO$ similar to those you look for $KU$. I presume there is also a note on $KU$.